# Stripping everything starting with character not included in list

Tags: python, string, xpath, strip

With code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

tree = html.fromstring(requests.get('http://selectshop.pl/deskorolka-blaty-decki,40/1').content)
print [elem.encode('utf8').replace(',','.') for elem in    tree.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()')]
```

I'm getting list of strings like `'189.00 z\xc5\x82'`. 
I would like to remove `z\xc5\x82` part from every element of list. I can use `.strip(' z\xc5\x82')` but I rather would like to remove everything starting from first character (from left) that is not in list `['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.']`
because string to remove may differ in some cases. How to do this?

Comment: How might the string differ in some cases? I had a look at the website and didn't see any exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.isdigit) with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to filter only digits and dots, then [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join filtered characters back to a string:

```
>>> ''.join(c for c in '189.00 z\xc5\x82' if c.isdigit() or c == '.')
'189.00'
```

---

```
>>> allowed_chars = set(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.'])
# OR   allowed_chars = set('0123456789.')
>>> ''.join(c for c in '189.00 z\xc5\x82' if c in allowed_chars)
'189.00'
```

Comment: How can I incorporate this method into my line `print [elem.encode('utf8').replace(',','.') for elem in    tree.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()')]` to get a list of modified strings?

Comment: @MichałRzepecki, Define a function: `def strip_non_number(s): return ''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit() or c == '.')`, then call it inside the list comprehension: `print [strip_non_number(elem.encode('utf8').replace(',','.')) for elem in tree.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()')] `

Comment: Or define a function using the 2nd solution: `def strip_non_number(s, allowed_chars = set('0123456789.')): return ''.join(c for c in s if c in allowed_chars)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) for that, something like:

```
import re

s = "189.00 z\xc5\x82"
s = re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", s)

print(s) # prints "189.00"
```

Thus you need to change this part:

```
elem.encode('utf8').replace(',','.')
```

Into:

```
re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", elem.encode('utf8').replace(',','.'))
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` inside `[....]` because special characters lose it's meaning inside `[...]`. (except `-`, `^`, ...)

Comment: @falsetru Ahh, you're right. It's a habit of mine to always do so.

Comment: Also `s = "189.00 z\\xc5\\x82"` should be `s = "189.00 z\xc5\x82"`. Otherwise, if you run the code in the answer,  `189.00582` will be printed.

Comment: How can I incorporate this method into my line `print [elem.encode('utf8').replace(',','.') for elem in    tree.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()')]` to get a list of modified strings?

Comment: @MichałRzepecki, `print [re.sub(r'[^\d.], '', elem.encode('utf8').replace(',','.')) for elem in tree.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()')]`

Comment: @falsetru I deleted my other comment (less clutter). I realized what you meant as I decided to test it.